# NServiceBus - "project type is not supported" error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: nservicebus

Installation of NServiceBus was smooth and straightforward. No issues there.

Now, I'm trying to play with a sample solution to see what happens behind the screens. Just trying to follow instructions here - http://docs.particular.net/samples/

And I get this error when creating an endpoint.

[image]

Reinstalled the VS add-in. Restarted VS 2010. No luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are 2 add-ins in the gallery, did you get the wrong one maybe?

Comment: I installed the VSIX that came from the NServiceBus 3.2.8 zip folder. And in fact, it was kicked off by the RunMeFirst.bat file. I didn't install it from the gallery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you don't have the ASP NET MVC 3 project type installed on your environment. Please try installing ASP.Net MVC from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

If you have tried to install it using the Web Platform Installer Tool, be sure that you installed the right version and product (At least for me, it's easy to pick the wrong one with so many similar named products).

Comment: Seems like that was it. Installing MVC 3 has been failing regardless of how I choose to do it (Web Platform Installer or direct download from the site). But that's a different issue. So I won't be able to say for sure (yet), but it seems very likely that not having the MVC 3 project template is what's causing the problem. So I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: That was it for sure. Confirmed. Thanks for your help.